# Can I deploy app to iphone 3gs iOS 4 from XCode_3.1.4_iPhone_SDK_3.1.2 directly

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, ios4

Currently I installed **XCode_3.1.4_iPhone_SDK_3.1.2** on **Mac OSX 10.5.8**, and I plan to buy an iphone 3gs 8G **iOS 4** in the following days. I heard from friends that iOS 4 can't be downgraded to 3.x!

My question is, can XCode_3.1.4_iPhone_SDK_3.1.2 deploy app to iOS 4 device via **iDP**? Should I upgrade system to **10.6.4** and **install Xcode_3.2.3_iOS_SDK_4.0.2**?

For **jailbreak iOS 4**, does **ldid** still work well? Or some other tools for code signing?

I didn't try with iOS 4 yet, so could you give me some help, thanks in advance.

Email/MSN: linkou.bian@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this has been changed, but you used to be able (when xcode was around 3.1ish) still be able to install onto 2.2.1 even though xcode didnt recognize it. Just had to build the app with deploy targetted to 2.2.1 and then get the .app and move it to itunes, then sync your itunes with the phone and it worked.

Comment: a friend from http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=306328 told me I should use the latest sdk for iOS 4...

I'm a little confusing... Maybe I have to test it myself.